# TinyMCE - Hide the toolbar and makes it appear when textarea is clicked

Tags: tinymce, textarea

I would like the toolbar of TinyMCE to be only displayed when the user clicks in the textarea.

Any clue how to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried TinyMCE's inline mode?

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/inline/